# Can "aussi" be used to mean "either"?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, coordination

> The cinema is not so far, but it is not so close either.

The translation of "either" is "non plus", so it would be

> (a) Le cinéma n'est pas très loin, mais il n'est pas très près non plus.

Can we use "aussi" in this sense?

> (b) Le cinéma n'est pas très loin, mais il n'est pas très près aussi.

Comment: Even if it would be understood I would not say *aussi* in your example. Usually *Aussi* is used in affirmative sentences, in negative sentences stick to *non plus*.  [Aussi ou non plus?](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/2881.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, "non plus" is the appropriate word in this sentence since the second clause is negative.

The sentence can also be translated:

> Le cinéma n'est ni loin, ni très près.

Other valid sentence example:

> Le cinéma est cher, mais il n'est pas très loin non plus.